sssd adjust ldap_search_ext
is possible to adjust the used filters in the ldap search query in the sssd.conf?
Background:
I/We want to implement ldap authentication with sssd. Our sssd looks like:
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = test.de

[domain/test.de]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
enumerate = true
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_uri = ldaps://192.168.7.1:636, ldaps://192.168.7.2:636
ldap_search_base = ou=users, o=data
ldap_user_search_base = ou=users, o=data
ldap_user_object_class = posixAccount
ldap_user_name = uid
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
cache_credentials = true
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=ldap-clienttest,ou=sa,o=data
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = pawsd
debug_level = 9

My/Out problem is the resulting ldap search. Debugging the search for an user shows the ldap search query.
[(&(uid=testuser)(objekctclass=posixAccount)(uid=*)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][ou=users, o=data]

The search result will be 0 but if I search only for the uid (without the uidnumber)
(&(uid=testuser)(objekctclass=posixAccount)(uid=*))

I am getting the correct result.
How can I avoid using the given filter of the uidNumber?
Thanks.

Do the entries have uidNumber attributes at all?

We were already able to solve the problem. We just set the parameter ldap_user_uid_number = uid Because of the resulting ldapsearch, this will always be true.
Unfortunately, I noticed another problem in the logs: the entry found in the ldap directory could not be saved locally because the UID is not available. In the sssd.conf we set id_provider = ldap, if we use id_provider = localthe sssd service does not start.
Does anyone have suggestions for solving that problem?
